# Kendo Datasource new data sync

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource, kendo-grid

can i check what is new data on sync?

i have this:

```
$('#order_it').click(function(){
    gridNewData.sync(); // this will send data to server
});
```

gridNewData complete:

```
complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
    if (textStatus == 'success') {
        orders.read(); // this will refresh orders, and grid too, a
        gridNewData.data([]); // empty that temp datasource
    }
}
```

and:

```
var orders = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    autoSync: false,
    transport: {
        read: {
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: '/dokument/orders/',
            dataType: 'json',
            complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {

                // i think that here i need to get new synced items(or uids)

            }
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: 'id'
        }
    }
});
```

I need to make that rows in grid with another color, but can't find way to check what is new data.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get new uid's neither the items. What you can do is to iterate through the collection of data before you call sync() and search for "isdirty".